# PHP send and receive data

Tags: php

does anyone know how I would go about sending some data, to an external php page which will then pick up the data and process it.

I have a php page on one server which will send a userID and a date to a php page on a different server which will pick the data up and insert it into the mysql database. I don't want to redirect the user though from the page that they are on and if possible encrypt the data

Comment: could yo please improve your question by adding more detail concerning what you want to send? In any case, you could have a look into `xml_rpc`, `soap` and `curl`for server side communication.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I've gone for cURL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is use Json format to send the data.

You can compress it using gzcompress and mcrypt_encrypt to encrypt the data.

If you are storing passwords, best way is to hash it than any encryption.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to redirect, I'd suggest using `jQuery.post()`.
Find out more here: [jQuery.post documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to use JavaScripting/ajax to do this.  There are many different ways to do what you would like, so you will have to do more research on this to find a way that meets your comfort level.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it purely server side, you might want to look at CURL

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

This a great method of communicating between servers.

Also maybe look at Mcrypt for encrypting/decrypting data:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php